# Function to generate pyspark diff and return differences in line

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, hadoop

I have written a function that takes two pyspark dataframes and creates a diff in line. I am struggling to get it to scale with 100s of columns. I get around the `for` loop calling `.join()` hundreds of times. I am stuck, or maybe tired and looking for some suggestions!

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as sf


def diff_generate(df_one, df_two, pk):
# create df to join compared columns with
    diff_df = df_one.select(pk)
# ensure the PK is not in the schema to iterate needed cols
    if pk in df_one.schema.names:
        df_one.schema.names.remove(pk)
    for col in df_one.schema.names:
# ensure that col exists in df2
        if col in df_two.schema.names:
            df_two_ = df_two.select(pk, col)\
            .withColumnRenamed(col, "{}_compare".format(col))
            df = df_one.select(pk, col)\
            .subtract(df_two_)\
            .join(
                df_two_,
                pk, 
                "left_outer"
                )
# concat df columns to display comparison
            concat_df = df\
            .withColumn("{}_diff".format(col), 
                sf.concat(
                    sf.col(col), 
                    sf.lit("_compare:_"), 
                    sf.col("{}_compare".format(col))))\
            .select(pk, "{}_diff".format(col))
# join column 'diff' with initialized df 
            diff_df = diff_df.join(concat_df, pk, "left_outer")
    return diff_df
```

Sample result:

```
98723498,match,N_compare:_null,match,match,match,2018-05-15 18:37_compare:_2018-05-15 18:37:12,match,match
```

Comment: This code is at least missing some imports. Example usage would be appreciated as well. You say you're having scaling problems. Up to what amount does it still work as intended? Or does it work for all amounts but just very slow?

Comment: It works for all parts, just very slow when many columns are used - 100+...The number of rows doesn't seem to have much impact .  I have added the missing import.  Thanks!